# How to clear the connection pool for an OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbconnection

I am connection to an Access Database using a OleDatabase Connection. The problem is that I need to programmatically run the compact and repair operation on the database, however I can not do this while there are still open connections to the database.  The connections that exist are of course the connections from the connection pool from my program, however I can not seem to figure out how to clear the pool so that I can run the compact and repair.

I do have a using statement on all connections that get opened to the database so the problem is not that I am not disposing of the connections properly, the problem is the connection pool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the static method `ReleaseObjectPool` on the the `OleDbConnection` - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.releaseobjectpool.aspx

Comment: Thank you... I had found that but apparently overlooked the fact that I should call GC.Collect first!!!